# Taking values from database without loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Is it possible to query table and show certain columns without looping of all the results?

So, I have this query

```
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

Now I'm trying to get this columns

```
$shipping->option_one
$shipping->option_two
```

The error is obviously

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$preferences_option_one
>
> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$preferences_option_two

How can I do this?

`print_r($shipping)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [preferences_id] => 1
            [preferences_option_one] => Priority Mail
            [preferences_option_two] => Express Mail
        )

)
1
```

Error:

> [2017-05-30 10:06:10] production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of TypeError given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php on line 281 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/WhoopsDisplayer.php:43

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php line 281

```
protected function displayException($exception)
{
    $displayer = $this->debug ? $this->debugDisplayer : $this->plainDisplayer;

    return $displayer->display($exception);   <--- line 281
}
```

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/WhoopsDisplayer.php:43

```
public function display(Exception $exception) <-- line 43
{
    $status = $exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface ? $exception->getStatusCode() : 500;

    $headers = $exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface ? $exception->getHeaders() : array();

    return new Response($this->whoops->handleException($exception), $status, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you getting one row from the database then you should not use get() method at the end. You have to use first() method at the end of the query. So just change

```
From 
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->get();
To 
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->first();
or 
$shipping = Preferences::whereIn('preferences_id', 1)->first();
```

Now you can use

```
{{ $shipping->option_one }}
{{ $shipping->option_two }}
```

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: This return some meaningless to me error: `::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called...`

Comment: just make it `dd($shipping)` and show me the result as a screenshot

Comment: the output of print_r is by get() or first() ?

Comment: `get()` and `first()` same output for both.

Comment: Again this `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of TypeError given,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145435/discussion-between-sumon-mahmud-and-ivan).

Answer (score 0):

```
$shipping[0]->preferences_option_one
$shipping[0]->preferences_option_two
```

Comment: Now I got `ErrorException: Undefined offset: 1`

Comment: No errors now but this `This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: do one thing can you show the output of this print_r($shipping );

Comment: Again this error `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of TypeError given,` I don't even know what this means

Comment: in `logs/laravel.log` on page is just blank white page

Comment: can you post your display function??

Comment: Updated my question with function

Comment: this is core function of laravel. show where you are trying to display the answer we gave, that function of template or anything where you are trying to print out

Comment: I'm trying to save this in database, not to display it. This is on order submit and I saving the shipping method

Comment: ok so you have problem in that function, post that code where you are trying to insert in database

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've been busy to find out what is causing this error. Now all is good and I'm continue to try. So, now the error is same `ErrorException: Undefined offset: 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$pluck = $shipping->pluck('column', 'other')
$pluck->all()
```

Answer (score 0):

**the problem :**

```php
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->get();
```

will return a collection and you want to have an object.

so try

```
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->first();
```

or other ways to get 1 object from the collection of results where `'preferences_id', '=', 1`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below:

```
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->get();//it return collection of objects
```

So to get value use it like:

```
$shipping[0]->option_one
```

Or change method from `get()` to `first()`

```
$shipping = Preferences::where('preferences_id', '=', 1)->first();//it returns single value object
```

And get value like:

```
$shipping->option_one
```

Comment: when i use `->first();` it's return this PlainDisplayer::display() error