# Laravel : Is it possible to get all author directly from collection of books without looping?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have been trying to get all authors from collections of books.

```
$books = Books::all();
foreach($books as $book){ $book->author ...
```

This code will work, but i want to get all author without using loop

```
$allAuthorsThruBooks = Books::someQueryMaybe();
```

$allAuthorsThruBooks will show list of author.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Taking values from database without loop in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258215/taking-values-from-database-without-loop-in-laravel)

Comment: yes, it's called eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Do you want all authors list from all books of all author attached with every book ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your Model is inside Models directory `App\Models`

Books Model

```
use App\Models\Author;
...    

Class Books extends Model
{
   public function author()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Author::class, 'author_id');
   }
}
```

Query

```
$books = Books::with(['author'])->get();
// with condition
$books = Books::with(['author' => function($query)
   $query->where(...);
])->get();
```

Example Result

```
   [
      id: 1,
      name: 'Book One',
      author: [
         id: 1,
         name: 'Maddog'
      ]
   ],
   [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 01

Try  **pluck**

```
$authorList = collect($books)->pluck('author')->unique();
// use ->toArray() if you want to convert into array
```

---

### Method 02

Create helper

```
namespace App\Helpers;


use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class ArrHelper
{
    public static function onlyValues($array = [], $keys = [])
    {
        return array_filter(
            array_values(
                Arr::only($array, $keys)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

In controller

```
$authorList = collect(ArrHelper::onlyValues($books, ['author']));
```